# How to redirect to calling url after ajax call?

Tags: go

I have a controller function that is posted by ajax call:

```
func AddLike(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    fmt.Println("form posted \n\n")
    // Get session
    sess := session.Instance(r)
    var params httprouter.Params
    params = context.Get(r, "params").(httprouter.Params)
    Name := params.ByName("name")
   //do stuff
  //How to return to calling page?
}
```

This controller can be posted from several differnet urls. 
In the current situation, I see a blank page as the function returns to the url of ajax post, which is  `/addlike`.

I'm wondering how to return/redirect to the calling page after post being processed?

Comment: If i understood correctly you're having trouble redirecting?
If so have you tried/seen this.
http.Redirect(w, r, redirectURL, http.StatusFound)

Comment: Yes exacly, I wan to redirect to the calling page. The problem is that `redirectURL` can be many different urls.

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/ ? You can just write a response back at the end.   w.Write([]bytes)   , which will write back to the calling url... or if ajax is expecting a response in json you can use   json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(res)

Comment: You can look at the `referer` (sic) header

Comment: I could not find my answer in the docs, that's why I asked it on OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can use the `Referer` (sic) header and [`http.Redirect`](https://godoc.org/net/http#Redirect) to respond with a redirection.

```
func AddLike(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // TODO: Your stuff.

    redirectURL := r.Header.Get("Referer")
    if redirectURL == "" {
        // TODO: What to do in case you don't know
        // where to redirect.
        return
    }

    http.Redirect(w, r, redirectURL, http.StatusFound)
}
```

Comment: Yes. Indeed I used this one liner: `http.Redirect(w, r, r.Referer(), http.StatusFound) `